# javascript - change function onclick button (using another function)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make simple clicking game, but I have a problem. Let's say I have this:

```js
var clicks = 0;

function somefunction() {
  clicks++;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="somefunction()">BUTTON 1</button>
<button onclick="anothfunction()">BUTTON 2</button>
```

and here comes the problem. I want to count clicks on BUTTON 1, but after clicking on BUTTON 2. It will count one click as two clicks.
Thank you in advance. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the second button set a variable that's used by the first function.

```js
var clicks = 0;
var increment = 1;

function somefunction() {
  clicks += increment;
  console.log(clicks);
}
function anothfunction() {
    increment = 2;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="somefunction()">BUTTON 1</button>
<button onclick="anothfunction()">BUTTON 2</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. It helped me a lot.

Comment: Ok, I did. Thanks again. :-)